# Convolution derivative, $(f*g)'=f*g'$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, convolution

Let $f,g \in L^1$ and $g$ is differentiable and $g' \in L^1$, then $(f*g)'=f*g'$

**PROOF**: For this proof I am asked to use the dominated convergence theorem

It can be quickly arrived at that

$$\begin{align}
(f*g)'(x) &= \lim\limits_{h \to 0}  \int_\mathbb{R} f(t)\frac{g(x+h-t)-g(x-t)}{h}dt\\
\end{align}$$

For the following, it is necessary to interchange the limit and the integral and it is here where the theorem mentioned above is used.

To do so, it is sufficient to find a $k\in L^1$ such that
$|f(t)\frac{g(x+h-t)-g(x-t)}{h}|\leq k(t)$

However, I am having trouble finding such a function $k$

Comment: You need to assume that the derivative of g is integrable. Otherwise the convolution $f \ast g'$ is not well defined.

Comment: @MarcinKotowski Indeed, I forgot that hypothesis.

Comment: @reuns I have managed to arrive at this  $$ \left | \frac{g(x-t+h)-g(x-t)}{h} \right |=...=\left | \int_{0}^{1} {g}'(x-t+yh) dy \right |\leq \int_{0}^{1}\left | {g}'(x-t+yh) \right |dy $$  However, I am not able to narrow down $$\left | {g}'(x-t+yh) \right | $$ I would appreciate it if you could expand your comment a little more.